# How to know which Linux Distribution I'm using?

Tags: linux, linux-distributions

How to know which Linux Distribution I'm using?

`uname -a` gives

`Linux xxxxxx.net 2.6.9-42.0.3.EL.wh1smp #1 SMP Fri Aug 14 15:48:17 MDT 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux`

How can I know this is Ubuntu/Debian/Fedora or Redhat?

I uses `/etc/init.d/serviced restart` for restarting serevices, seems it is not Redhat family

```
[itf][~]$ cat /etc/issue
cat: /etc/issue: No such file or directory
[itf][~]$ cat /etc/issue.net
cat: /etc/issue.net: No such file or directory
[itf][~]$ lsb_release -a
-sh: lsb_release: command not found
[itf][~]$ cat /etc/*-release
cat: /etc/*-release: No such file or directory
[itf][~]$ cat /etc/*-version
cat: /etc/*-version: No such file or directory
[itf][~]$ cat /etc/*release
cat: /etc/*release: No such file or directory
[itf][~]$ cat /etc/*_release
cat: /etc/*_release: No such file or directory
[itf][~]$ cat /etc/*version
cat: /etc/*version: No such file or directory
[itf][~]$
```

Comment: If you want certain personal/confidential information to be removed, I think you can flag your question for moderator attention. Because we can still read it now...

Comment: @Tom Wijsman just want not to display that text in questions page, I know that will be there in history :-)

Answer (score 38):

- In Debian: `/etc/debian_version`
- In Ubuntu: `lsb_release -a or /etc/debian_version`
- In Redhat: `cat /etc/redhat-release`
- In Fedora: `cat /etc/fedora-release`

Comment: He tried all of them, see his source code.

Comment: +1, "lsb_release -a" worked for me on Red Hat.

Comment: `lsb_release -a` worked in Debian (squeeze), too.

Comment: `lsb_release -a` works in Gentoo as well

Comment: `lsb_release -a` works also in Ubuntu and Mint.

Comment: +1 `lsb_release -a` worked for me on boot2docker.

Comment: `lsb_release -ds` gives you the description with no column formatting. Tested on Ubuntu/Debian.

Answer (score 34):

Keep it simple!

```
cat /etc/*release
```

Answer (score 15):

You might try [this article from Novell](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/11251.html).

> If you are the owner of the system, then you know which Linux is installed and running. This article will help you to understand how to determine which Linux distribution is installed. You can incorporate this into your application to detect Linux distro.

Comment: I already tried $ cat /etc/*release
cat: /etc/*release: No such file or directory

Running the mensioned script gives a result simalr to uname -a command
Linux 2.6.9-42.0.3.EL.wh1smp( 2.6.9-42.0.3.EL.wh1smp i686)

$ uname -a
Linux qsquare.net 2.6.9-42.0.3.EL.wh1smp #1 SMP Fri Aug 14 15:48:17 MDT 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: `cat /etc/*release` seems to work for some of the mainstream distros.  I verified with Ubuntu, Mint, Red Hat, and Gentoo.

Comment: Debian does not recognize this

Comment: The Novell solution works, at last on my RedHat 5.3. I've integrated it in my free shell lib : https://github.com/Offirmo/offirmo-shell-lib

Comment: @nobar: It also works with SUSE distributions: `/etc/SuSE-release` http://pastebin.com/dL5gVLQe

Comment: Link in answer gives *"HTTP 404 Page Not Found"*.

Answer (score 8):

All [systemd](/questions/tagged/systemd) compliant systems will have [`/etc/os-release`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/os-release.html) which should give you information related to distribution etc

```
NAME=Fedora
VERSION="17 (Beefy Miracle)"
ID=fedora
VERSION_ID=17
PRETTY_NAME="Fedora 17 (Beefy Miracle)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;34"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:17"
HOME_URL="https://fedoraproject.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"
```

Answer (score 4):

Try one of these:

```
ls -ld /etc/\*release\*  /etc/\*version\*

gcc --version
```

Comment: Can I ask you why you are refusing to use markup for code? Please indent code by four spaces, that makes it so much easier to read and distinguish. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try http://legroom.net/2010/05/05/generic-method-determine-linux-or-unix-distribution-name.

> A combination of techniques that combines querying the LSB utilities, distro release info files, and kernel info from uname. It'll take the most specific distro name it can find, falling back to generic Linux if necessary. It'll also identify UNIX variants as well, such as Solaris or AIX.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Pre login message](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-change-login-message/) if it has not been edited

`cat /etc/issue`

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, maybe its another distro - the .EL suffix seems to be used by centos, but that's a redhat dervative. I'm also wondering what's your package management system? It might help to check whose repos you use- since these are usually vendor supplied, and distro specific

Answer (score 1):

[Check out this hack, that peeks at functions defined in startup scripts.](https://serverfault.com/questions/3331/how-do-i-find-out-what-version-of-linux-is-running/3334#3334)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to find out.
Here are 5 easy ones (debian-based distros):

> 1. Using the `lsb_release -a` command. This command displays information about your distribution, including the name, version,
>    description, and ID.
> 2. Using the `cat /etc/os-release` command. This command displays information about your operating system, including the distribution
>    name, version, and ID.
> 3. Using the `uname -a` command. This command displays information about your kernel, including the kernel version.
> 4. Using the `cat /proc/version` command. This command displays information about your kernel, including the kernel version and build.
> 5. Using the `hostnamectl` command. This command displays information about your operating system, including the distribution name, version,
>    and ID.

[Check the Version of Your Linux Distribution](https://linuxlifehacks.com/check-the-version-of-your-linux-distribution/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the kernel version I'd say it's [WBEL 4](http://www.beau.org/~jmorris/linux/whitebox/). They've been known to lag a bit with their updates, so it would probably be best to migrate to CentOS at your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Just putting the result into a var and in lowercase

```
OS=`awk -F= '/DISTRIB_ID/ {print tolower($2)}' /etc/lsb-release`
```

Answer (score 0):

An update here, now it is possible to use `lsb_release -ds`, so you can use it like `linuxDistro=$(lsb_release -ds)` with no extra parsing.

Answer (score 0):

The utilities `neofetch` and `screenfetch` both display your distribution name and version -- and they include some nice ASCII art.  They might not be installed by default, however.

- https://itsfoss.com/display-linux-logo-in-ascii