# How can I determine the distro of Linux that is running on a remote server?

Tags: linux

I am trying to know which version of Linux a remote server is running. I connected to my account there with SSH and used the following command:
uname -a

And I got:
Linux just103.justhost.com 2.6.32-20130307.60.9.bh6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Mar 7 15:58:33 EST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

But that doesn't tell me which version of Linux it is.

Any advice?
Thanks,

### Saul

There is a file lynx.cfg, so I did head lynx.cfg and it has:

The default placement for this file is /etc/lynx.cfg (Red Hat Linux, Fedora)

So, does it meas that the system is Red Hat linux or Fedora?

Comment: Most systems these days have [lsb_release](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lsb_release).

Comment: Did you want the kernel version, or the distro name? You already get the kernel version with `uname -a` (see harald's answer).

Comment: I want the distro name.

Comment: [Related/duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864734/how-to-know-which-linux-distribution-im-using). You may have difficulties since your kernel version indicates an older Linux release. Try `cat /etc/issue`.

Comment: [Related Super User question](http://superuser.com/questions/80251/how-to-know-which-linux-distribution-im-using), since this question was migrated from Stack Overflow.

Comment: Did you try the social approach? Simply ask the server owner/admin.

Answer (score 9):

Try this...

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
```

Comment: There is not release* file into the /etc directory.

Comment: @SaulLugo It's `*-release`, not `release*`. For instance, I'm running Arch Linux, so I have `arch-release`, `lsb-release`, and `os-release` in `/etc/`.

Comment: [/etc]# ls *-release /bin/ls: cannot access *-release: No such file or directory

Comment: Saul, have you tried `cat /etc/issue` as I indicated in my comment on your question? The linked Stack Overflow question indicated that command may work out on older distros.

Answer (score 9):

If you are lucky, some information can be obtained by running

```
lsb_release -a
```

Comment: No luck, I don't have the command lsb_release in my system.

Answer (score 4):

"2.6.32-20130307.60.9.bh6.x86_64" suggests CentOS or RedHat Linux. To find out what version of CentOS it is (if it is CentOS), use:

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
```

or more generally:

```
cat /etc/*release
```

Another way to go about it is to look in /etc for configuration files, like update servers and repositories, which are distro-specific.

This:

```
cat /etc/issue*
```

might also provide some clues.

Yet another way to go about it is to look for which package manager is installed. Try these:

```
apt-get -v
yum --version
pacman --version
emerge --version
pkgtool
```

If you find one them, use them to search for a "lsb-release" or similarly named package, and if found, install it and try:

```
lsb_release -a
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using nmap's OS detection:  http://nmap.org/book/man.html

Comment: Oh, you've have a login on the box, nm

Comment: ... and that would just yield `Linux 3` anyways, and not a  specific distribution

Answer (score 0):

Check all `/etc/*` in this function:

https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/059f44a4d42ccfa5006b02fc4b01784ac5440eab/salt/grains/core.py#L671

Answer (score 0):

If its debian check

```
cat /etc/debian_version
```

or more genrally

```
cat /etc/*-release
cat /etc/*version
```

should match most distros

Answer (score 0):

If you have `yum` command available then it is a RedHat/CentOS/Oracle then check your `yum` repository settings.

If you have `apt-get` then it is Debian related and again check your software repositories to find out exactly what distribution it is.

If you don't have any of them, then ask the person who created your user account ;)